# Django RestFramework _'NoneType' object has no attribute 'token'

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have this Serializer class for  my User model:
serializers.py

```
class UserCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """User django serilization"""
    key = serializers.StringRelatedField(source='key.token', read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['phonenumber','id','email', 'username', 'key' ]

    def create(self, validate_data):
        user = User(**validate_data)
        user.save()
        return user
```

and this views.py

```
class UserListView(ListAPIView):
    '''listing all users'''
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)
    pagination_class = SmallPagination
    throttle_classes = (UserRateThrottle, AnonRateThrottle,)
    serializer_class = UserCreateSerializer
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    filter_backends = (filters.SearchFilter,)
    search_fields = ('username', 'phonenumber', 'email')
```

I include **'rest_framework.authtoken',**  in my settings.py
and made a signal for Tokens from django Restframe work documentation.

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
def create_auth_token(sender, instance=None, created=False, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Token.objects.create(user=instance)
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'^users/$', views.UserListView.as_view(), name='user-list'),]
```

so when I try to load my users List this error occurs :

> 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'token'

```
 for attr in attrs:
        try:
            if isinstance(instance, collections.Mapping):
                instance = instance[attr]
            else:
                instance = getattr(instance, attr) ...
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            return None
        if is_simple_callable(instance):
            try:
                instance = instance()
            except (AttributeError, KeyError) as exc:
....
```

the error location is from :

> /backend/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/fields.py in
>   get_attribute

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/users/create/

Django Version: 2.0
Python Version: 3.6.3
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'main.apps.MainConfig',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'rest_framework',
 'stdimage',
 'rest_framework.authtoken',
 'blog',
 'taggit',
 'taggit_serializer',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'corsheaders',
 'webpack_loader']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "/home/babyjesus/workspace/gamespawn/backend/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  35.             response = get_response(request)

File "/home/babyjesus/workspace/gamespawn/backend/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  128.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/home/babyjesus/workspace/gamespawn/backend/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  126.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/home/babyjesus/workspace/gamespawn/backend/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py" in wrapped_view
  54.         return view_func(*args, **kwargs)

File "/home/babyjesus/workspace/gamespawn/backend/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
  69.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/babyjesus/workspace/gamespawn/backend/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in dispatch
  494.             response = self.handle_exception(exc)

File "/home/babyjesus/workspace/gamespawn/backend/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in handle_exception
  454.             self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)

File "/home/babyjesus/workspace/gamespawn/backend/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in dispatch
  491.             response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/babyjesus/workspace/gamespawn/backend/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/generics.py" in post
  192.         return self.create(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/babyjesus/workspace/gamespawn/backend/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/mixins.py" in create
  22.         headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)

File "/home/babyjesus/workspace/gamespawn/backend/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py" in data
  537.         ret = super(Serializer, self).data

File "/home/babyjesus/workspace/gamespawn/backend/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py" in data
  262.                 self._data = self.to_representation(self.instance)

File "/home/babyjesus/workspace/gamespawn/backend/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py" in to_representation
  491.                 attribute = field.get_attribute(instance)

File "/home/babyjesus/workspace/gamespawn/backend/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/relations.py" in get_attribute
  177.         return get_attribute(instance, self.source_attrs)

File "/home/babyjesus/workspace/gamespawn/backend/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/fields.py" in get_attribute
  100.                 instance = getattr(instance, attr)

Exception Type: AttributeError at /api/users/create/
Exception Value: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'token'
```

Comment: can you show all code when you use instance? I think the error is there

Comment: @AndreyBerendaI don't follow you. the error comes from rest_framework. and for detail, I use Django abstractbaseuser.I suspicious the token model and user are not compatible. and the signal cannot work with my custom User model

Answer (score 0):

`authtoken` model has `related_name=auth_token` to user models. So if you need to get token from user you should use `auth_token.key`:

```
key = serializers.StringRelatedField(source='auth_token.token', read_only=True)
```

Comment: same error again. why is nothing on the internet about this error? look at my full traceback in my question

Answer (score 0):

I also got stuck in this error. But luckily i found the mistake i was doing.
I know its already been some time now. Still answering this question for newbies stuck in such silly error.
If we have to use Token model we have to mention the same in **Installed Apps** in **settings.py** file

```
'rest_framework.authtoken'
```

After that do migrate and you will see creation of new tables in the db.
Afterwards you can query the database like this...

```
Token.objects.all()
```

and you are good to go now.

Happy coding.